# React Native TextInput blur consumes TouchableHighlight press event

Tags: ios, react-native

I have a `<TextInput>` that I'd like to submit when I tap the red Post button, a `<TouchableHighlight>`. When the TextInput is focused, I finish typing and I tap on the Post button, the keyboard closes but the button doesn't register the tap.

I tried using the TextInput `onBlur` event, but It doesn't give me the coordinates of the touch point, so I don't know if the touch point is actually over the button or not.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to add the property keyboardShouldPersistTaps={true} to your ScrollView.

Here is what the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#content) say :

> **keyboardShouldPersistTaps bool:**
>
> When false, tapping outside of the focused text input when the
>   keyboard is up dismisses the keyboard. When true, the scroll view will
>   not catch taps, and the keyboard will not dismiss automatically. The
>   default value is false.

Comment: Thank you!
Btw, this option is also available for ListView.

Comment: Still didn't quite solve the problem. What if I want tapping outside the textbox to dismiss the keyboard as well? I want taps on the button to have highest priority, and every other tap outside the textbox should dismiss the keyboard.

Comment: `keyboardShouldPersistTaps` is now deprecated as a boolean. Use `keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"` instead. [React native documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html)

Comment: did you find proper solution? @frank

Answer (score 8):

@frank, I imagine you found a workable solution, but in addition to the 'keyboardShouldPersistTaps', if you wrap your view in a TouchableWithoutFeedback element with an onPress that calls dismissKeyboard it should fix the issue.

```
 <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps={true} ref='scrollView'>
   <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={dismissKeyboard}>
     <View>
     -View Content-
     </View>
  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: this doesn't work if you have clickable elements in the content area.